# iTunes accounts and family sharing

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-id, sharing

I have an old / original email that I use for iTunes / App Store purchases. I have since setup an iCloud / Apple ID for myself and also added family members to that account.

Currently I have been logging my family members into my original iTunes account for purchase sharing. But if purchases are shared, do I need to do this or can they all just log in with one ID? And if this is the case, can’t I add the iTunes account as a member of my family and also log into all of my own devices with a single Apple ID while still retaining the App Store purchase history?

What is the best way to accomplish this? Ideally I would like to use the original iTunes ID as little as possible but still retain purchase history and sharing across the family.